# How to calculate standard deviation with R for a file with a single numeric column?

Tags: statistics, r

I have a file with the following data:

```
12341231
1231312
1233123
1231313
523454
6567
73525
```

I would like to read the file into an R object and calculate STD on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use `scan` for that file. You don't need to construct a data frame to calculate standard deviation on a vector.  `scan` reads the data and gives a vector and it is faster than `read.table` for what you're doing here.

```
## put your data into a file, "new.txt"
> txt <- '12341231
  1231312
  1233123
  1231313
  523454
  6567
  73525'
> writeLines(txt, "new.txt")
## read and calculate standard deviation
> x <- scan("new.txt", what = integer())
> x
# [1] 12341231  1231312  1233123  1231313   523454     6567    73525
> sd(x)
# [1] 4426815
```